# I want to convert a php/mysql application to a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a php/mysql web application.I want to convert it in a wordpress plugin.How can I make link of one php file to another file.
For example I have plugin tw. tw.php is its index file and the other file name is tw1.php.

first page

```
/* plugin name:tw
 plugin url:httpL://csr.estheticsolutions.com.pk
*/

//tell wordpress to register the demolistposts shortcode
add_shortcode("demo-list-posts", "demolistposts_handler");

  function demolistposts_handler()  
    {
    //run function that actually does the work of the plugin
     $demolph_output = my_function();
     //send back text to replace shortcode in post
      return $demolph_output;
     }


 function my_function()
     {
?>
          <html>
          <body>          


               <form   action="tw1.php" method="post">
                       <input  type="text" name="fname"  >
                       <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
                </form>


          </body>
          </html>
 <?php


  }


 ?>
```

second page

```
<?php

 $First_Name=$_POST['fname'];
echo $First_Name;

?>
```

when i submit value in tw.php ,an error appears tw1.php not found(404) in wordpress folder,then i paste the file tw1.php in that(wordpress) folder and  submit, posted  value get in new page without wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with name=people with columns: id, firstname, lastname, DateofBirth, addressid, fatherid, motherid. Have suitable column properties with each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin url function to link to the second file:

```
           <form   action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'tw1.php', dirname(__FILE__) ); ?>" method="post">
                   <input  type="text" name="fname"  >
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
            </form>
```